# Where point razor folders "_framework" and "_content"?

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

Where point razor folders "_framework" and "_content"?

_host.cshtml

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorInputFile/inputfile.js"></script>
```

there is no inputfile.js nor a BlazorInputFile folder

Answer (score 2):

simple answer for _content: to wwwroot of those library.

what about _framework? Root directory of library?

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was raised in a Blazor component vendor's support forum and the answer was that _content/SomeComponent references the Nuget download package.

The location of local Nuget downloads can be configured in Visual Studio.